# Sql Server Extract String

Tags: sql-server, replace, substring, charindex

I have following Table

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (COL NVARCHAR(MAX))
insert @TABLE values
('[E=110][D=1]'),
('[E=110][D=NE]'),
('[E=110][D=U$]'),
('[E=110][D=FX]')
```

I am trying to extract data as followed

```
COL           || EXCEPTION_CODE    ||  DATA
=========================================
[E=110][D=1]  ||     110           || 1
[E=110][D=NE] ||     110           || NE
[E=110][D=U$] ||     110           || U$
[E=110][D=FX] ||     110           || FX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML gives more flexibility then `charindex`. `replace` is very useful to prepare well-formed xml. See code.

```
;with dat(col, x) as (
select col, cast('<col'+replace(
                         replace(
                           replace(col,'=','="'),
                         ']','" '),
                        '[',' ')+' />' as xml)
from @TABLE
)
select col, t.v.value('@E','int') Exception_code, t.v.value('@D','varchar(100)') [DATA]
from dat cross apply x.nodes('col') t(v)
```

And results are as desired in OP.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the functions SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX.
Using those together you should be able to extract this.

SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )

CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )

For example:

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(COL,CHARINDEX('E=',COL)+2,CHARINDEX(']',COL) - CHARINDEX('E=',COL) - 2)
FROM @TABLE
```

will get you the EXCEPTION_CODE column.